# Cannot get gocode to work

Tags: go

Hi I was try trying play around with gocode tool but since it has poor documentation I cannot figure out how it works. I've read

https://github.com/nsf/gocode/blob/master/docs/IDE_integration.md

I created a simple test file (path is `d:\papa\papa.go`):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)
func main() {
    fmt.
}
```

It seems obvious that I want to get compilation for the `fmt.` part (to see functions and everything else exported from that package. Now I run

```
gocode -s -debug
```

And than

```
gocode -in=d:/papa/main.go -f=nice autocomplete 51
```

Here is gocode's output:

```
Found 2 candidates:
  func main()
  package fmt
```

It is not what I'd expect as you can see.

In the debug output I seen something interesting:

> 2017/04/10 15:58:15 Go project path: .
>
> 2017/04/10 15:58:15 Got autocompletion request for 'd:/papa/main.go'
>
> 2017/04/10 15:58:15 Cursor at: 51
>
> 2017/04/10 15:58:15

---

> package main
>
> import (
>
> ```
>     "fmt"
> ```
>
> )
>
> # func main() {
>
> ```
>     fmt.
> ```
>
> }

---

> 2017/04/10 15:58:15 Found "fmt" at "D:\Go\pkg\windows_386\fmt.a"
>
> 2017/04/10 15:58:15 Error parsing input file (inner block):
>
> 2017/04/10 15:58:15  4:1: expected selector or type assertion, found '}'
>
> 2017/04/10 15:58:15  4:2: expected ';', found 'EOF'
>
> 2017/04/10 15:58:15  4:2: expected '}', found 'EOF'
>
> 2017/04/10 15:58:15 Offset: 0
>
> 2017/04/10 15:58:15 Number of candidates found: 2
>
> 2017/04/10 15:58:15 Candidates are:
>
> 2017/04/10 15:58:15   func main()
>
> 2017/04/10 15:58:15   package fmt

Needless to say there is no actual error during go build on this code.

So

1. Why gocode doesn't provide with the relevant info?
2. What is the deal about those "errors")?

Comment: What are you expecting? `fmt.` is simply invalid syntax, there's nothing the compiler can do with that. It's an illegal statement. The end. If you want to see whatever is in the `fmt` package, look at the source code (it's open). Because you mention IDE integration: any IDE will autocomplete `fmt.` anyway

Comment: He is not trying to compile this code, but to use gocode to obtain autocomplete suggestions. And any IDE will autocomplete because many of them use gocode.

Comment: @Zoyd: In which case, either use existing plugins, or read the manual I'd say: https://github.com/nsf/gocode. However, if you're using vim, I'd go for _fatih/vim-go_ and either YCM or neocomplete. Either one works

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem

As  Zoyd pointed out, I am trying to manually get autocomplete tips from gocode. I for sure know about plugins that make use of this tool, however I have reasons to solve the task in question (those reasons are out of scope of the discussion).

Another thing I am wondering about is why gocode reports listed errors (they're reported even with `fmt.` being removed and I didn't think gocode would expect the valid code as when a user requests autocompletion  their code is often not complete/valid)

Comment: For this kind of stuff, I always look at the source of either `vim-go` or Atom's `go-plus` as they have already done the heavy lifting in parsing the parameters to send, and parsing the output of the tools.